# PHP - Foreach loop - echo selected value

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, foreach

I've made something like a **crud system for employees**.

The user can input informations about the employees. Under others, there is a 'select' input with couple of options that come from the database. When I fill out the form, and submit it, the data gets to the database.

But when I want to edit the form, the 'select' input gets another value, even if I don't change anything there. So I need something to echo the already inputed value from the option.

This is my foreach loop that I use to loop the categories:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach($categories as $key => $category) {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $category; ?>"><?php echo $category; ?></option>
    <?php
    $i++;
}
?>
```

How to get the value from the database that was selected and stored there.
    Thanks

Comment: have u looked in your database if it is properly storing those exact values which u submitted?

Comment: @Rasika it does. It work well, until I want to edit users profile. Then, even if I don't touch the select input, it get's a new value. Let's say there are 4 options (a,b,c,d), first time I choose 'b'. It get's stored as 'b'. Later when I edit any info on the profile the value of the select input get's overwritten by lets say 'a'.

Comment: then the problem must be in your "update" query or its values. hows it possible that it changes its value automatically? does it shows the exact data in database which u edit and updated.

Comment: Readability... Is `$categories` data from your SQL query? Or are you asking how to connect to a Database and output each category associated within the database corresponding to that array? It's pretty unclear, like your code.

Comment: @KDOT I'm asking, how can i echo the selected value in this foreach loop.

Comment: have you `print_r()` on `$categories` because I see nothing wrong with the code unless your array is empty.

Comment: What are you doing with `$i++` ? For what you need it?

Comment: @KDOT I don't think there is much wrong with the code, but there is missing something which would echo the already selected value from the database. Right now, whichever value I had, it get's overwritten by the default option from the select input.

Comment: @Twinfriends was mistake didn't change that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML `<option>` tag has property `selected` that you should use, it specifies that an option should be pre-selected:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$selected_category = "B"; // category value from database
foreach($categories as $key => $category) {
    $selected = ($selected_category == $category) ? "selected" : "";
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $category; ?>" <?php echo $selected; ?>>
    <?php echo $category; ?></option>
<?php
    $i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: But I can't hardcode the categorie values, as I can add them dinamical

Comment: *category value from database* - which means you get the last known selected value from your database/cache or however you're storing it @amircisija

Comment: alright, I added $selected_category =  $edit_row["rm_cat"];. It works now. When I open the profile to edit. the Option value gets the selected. Thank you so much.